# I want to write the XQuery to print the specific keys in JSON

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

This is my sample JSON

```
{
"id":"743",
"groupName":"group1",
"transation":{
    "101":"success",
    "102":"rejected",
    "301":"processing"
     }
}
```

Expected Result:

```
"101"
"102"
"301"
```

Can anyone please help me to print the above result using XQuery?

I can achieve this through JavaScript, but I need to write in XQuery.

Comment: var jsonData = {"id":"743","groupName":"Ggroup1","transaction":{"101":"success ","102":"rejected","301":"processing"}};
var keys = [];
for(var i in jsonData){
    var key = i;
    var val = jsonData[i];
    if(key == "transaction")
    {
    for(var j in val){
        var sub_key = j;
        keys.push(sub_key);
    }
    }
}
keys. This is my Java script code but I need to achieve in Xquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not knowing how you are reading the JSON document, whether as a doc in the database or parsing a JSON string, below uses `xdmp:unquote()` to parse a string, but you could instead just read the document from the database with `fn:doc()` or through `cts:search()`.

Then, you could just XPath to the `transation` fields and return those node names with the `name()` function:

```
let $jsonData := xdmp:unquote('
{
"id":"743",
"groupName":"group1",
"transation":{
    "101":"success",
    "102":"rejected",
    "301":"processing"
     }
}')
return 
  $jsonData/transation/*/name()
```

Comment: Thanks, This is so simple :)